# Continuity and Differentiability Q

Tags: derivatives, continuity

We have f = e^(-1/|x|) if x is not equal to 0 and f(0) = p.

Question 1: for what value(s) of p is f differentiable at 0?
Question 2: is f' continuous for the values found in question 1?

What I tried for question 1:

f is differentiable for the values at which the limit as h goes to 0 of (f(h) - f(o))/h exist. If I continue down this route I get to f'(0) = lim h->0 1/(h*e^(-1/|h|)) - lim h->0 p/h. How should I continue?

And for question 2: if we can differentiate a function at some point then that function is by definition also continuous at that point, because continuity is a condition for differentiability.

Appreciating all input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question (1), note that you correctly wrote that $f$ has to be continuous at 0 for being differentiable at that point, hence let's find 
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = \lim_{h\to 0} \exp(-|h|^{-1}) = 0 $$
Hence $f$ is continuous at $0$ iff $p = 0$, so we must have $p =0 $. Now we can ask whether 
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - 0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}\exp(-|h|^{-1}) $$
exists, and as $\exp$ grows faster then every polynomial, we have that the limit exists, and equals $f'(0) = 0$.

For question (2), note that it's not the continuity of $f$ what is asked, but the continuity of $f'$, which does not follow from its existence. We have that 
$$ f'(x) = \begin{cases} \mathop{\rm sgn} x \cdot |x|^{-2} \exp(-|x|^{-1}), & x \ne 0\\
                            0, & x = 0
           \end{cases} 
$$
But, as (again by known properties of $\exp$ mentioned above) 
$$ f'(0) = 0 = \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) 
  $$
$f'$ is continuous at $0$.